# redux-saga: Cancelling multiple tasks of the same action type / saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I'm trying to figure out how to incorporate cancelling of multiple tasks of the same action type in redux-saga. Basically, when my component is in `componentWillUnmount()`, I want to cancel all tasks that it may have started.

If I have the following action (this is greatly simplified from what I actually have in my code, but I'm trying to pare it down to the essentials):

```
// Action
export const loadMyData = params => {
  let url = /* Create URL based on params */
  return {
    type: FETCH_DATA,
    url,
    key: /* a unique key so we can retrieve it in the state later */
  }
}
```

And the following saga:

```
// Saga
export function* fetchData(action) {
  try {
    // 'callApi()' currently uses axios
    let response = yield call(callApi, action.url);

    yield put({
      type: FETCH_SUCCESS,
      key: action.key,
      payload: response.data
   });
  } catch(error) {
    yield put({
      type: FETCH_FAILURE,
      error
    });
  }
}

export function* watchFetchData() {
  while (true) {
    let action = yield take(FETCH_DATA);
    let task = yield fork(fetchApi, action);
  }
}
```

As stated above, the component may call `loadMyData()` multiple times. Furthermore, there may have other components that also call `loadMyData()`. So I'm trying to find a way to cancel the tasks from just the component that is in the `componentWillUnmount()` state, but leave any other running tasks intact.

In the [Redux Saga Cancellation documentation](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/TaskCancellation.html), their example is for a single task that expects a cancellation action after. And I can't figure out how to extend that to my use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What comes to my mind is the following:

In `componentWillMount` you register your component by dispatching an action and storing the tasks in a reducer like so:

```
registerWatchFetchData = (componentKey) => {
  return {
     type: "REGISTER_WATCH_FETCH_DATA",
     payload: { componentKey }
  }
}
```

reducer:

```
// ...
case "REGISTER_WATCH_FETCH_DATA": 
  return {...state, tasks: {...state.tasks, [action.payload.componentKey]: []}}
```

Then inside `function* watchFetchData()` you store the new task in the reducer for the corresponding component keying on componentKey which you provide in the `payload`:

```
export function* watchFetchData() {
  while (true) {
    let action = yield take(FETCH_DATA);
    let task = yield fork(fetchApi, action);
    yield put({ type: "STORE_TASK", payload: { componentKey: action.payload.componentKey, task } })
  }
}
```

then add to the reducer

```
// ...
case "STORE_TASK": 
  return {...state, tasks: {...state.tasks, [action.payload.componentKey]: [...state.tasks[action.payload.componentKey], action.payload.task]}}
```

And in `componentWillUnmount` you dispatch another action to tell a saga to pull all tasks for the componentKey, iterate through them and cancel them all like so:

```
function* watchUnregisterComponent(){
    while(true){
        const action = yield take("UNREGISTER_WATCH_FETCH_DATA")
        const componentTasks = yield select(state => state.myReducer.tasks[action.payload.componentKey])
        componentTasks.forEach((t) => {
           yield cancel(t)
        })
        // dispatch another action to delete them from the reducer
    }
}
```